# Why png image loses color?

Tags: color, logo, png, color-conversion, jpg

I have provided the client a logo (black and white) for Instagram in png.
According to the client when he uploaded png image, the black part of image changes to green.

Can anybody tell me why this happened?

Also when I viewed my delivered images in iphone, some images black part is not visible and for some black part changed to brown.

Comment: Whenever an image is uploaded to a web site, the web site itself *represses* the image*. There's no telling what it can do in that process.

Comment: is there any example for the rendered image you sent to your client?
My guessing should be due to screen display issue.

Comment: @Scott "represses" or "recompresses"?

Comment: Reprocesses -- most often resizes and at time swill change formats. I.e. to jpg or to png.

Comment: Is it possible you used a rich black (CMYK) or a custom color such as Pantone? What software did you use to make the logo and PNG file?

Comment: @user8356 Adobe Illustrator

Comment: @user8356 I used CMYK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the OP, the image was created with CMYK colors in Illustrator, and saved as PNG. But PNG format does NOT support CMYK colors, so there had to be a conversion when the file was saved. Previewing the file in several image programs (GIMP and IrfanView are two free ones) would show the result. It's entirely possible that the conversion resulted in the strange color shift you describe.

For files that are going to be printed, use CMYK and a file format that supports CMYK and is used by professional printers: TIFF, EPS, or PDF are the most common. If the logo is mainly for screen display, use RGB colors and save as JPEG, PNG or GIF.